# How do I change the background color of a unicode symbol?

Tags: css

I'm trying to keep the unicode ace of hearts U+1F0B1 white with a green body background. I'm thinking that I need to create a div with the same size as the card and set that to white. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the sample way. but you need to adjust the "text-indent" and the "letter-spacing" depending on the font-size of the unicode. 
See code below

```css
body {
background: grey;
}
i {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
i::before{
   content: "\1F0B1";
    font-style: normal;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    line-height: 0.8;
    font-size: 150px;
    background: green;
    letter-spacing: -10px;
    text-indent: -10px;

}
```

```html
<i class="heart"></i>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in a single HTML element as well, with a pseudo-class. Similar to how icon sets work these days.

```css
i {
  background: green;
  font-style: normal;
  padding: 2px 4px;
}

i::before {
  content: "\1F0B1";
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<i class="heart"></i>
```